# Temporarily modifying fields in a const member function

Tags: c++, mutable, const-cast

Suppose that we have a class `A` with a member function `f`.
To the outside world, `f` simply computes a value without modifying anything of `A`; but in the implementation, it does temporarily modify `A`:

```
class A
{
    int f() const
    {
        tiny_change(b); // since copying "b" is expensive
        int result = compute(b);
        tiny_recover(b); // "b" backs to the original value
        return result;
    }

    B b;
}
```

Of course the code above does not compile. Here are two workarounds I know:

1. `const_cast<A*>(this)->b`
2. `mutable B b;`

None of these solutions is perfect. The solution 1 involves UB when an instance of `A` itself is `const`; and the solution 2 exposes the mutable-ness to the whole class such that it cannot prevent the coder from accidentally modifying `b` in other `const` member functions.

`const_cast` is "local", but may trigger UB; `mutable` is memory-safe, but too "global".

So is there a third solution, or am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: Can't you instead of `tiny_change(b)` develop sort of `tiny_change(result)` and compute result on non changed `B`.

Comment: Can't you just overload `compute` to take the "small change" and use that instead of whatever value `b` has? `B` is obviously related to the logical const-ness of your class, and not just the bitwise one. Both solutions are hacks in this case.

Comment: @Zereges those functions are not homomorphic in my case

Comment: @StoryTeller In my case `B` is a big array and the "small change" may happen to any array element. `compute(b)` is based on CPU-sensitive recursion so directly modifying `b` might be the cheapest.

Comment: Be careful of this approach in a multi-threaded context.  It is common for const member functions to be thread-safe.  If you are changing `b` then that is not the case and you would need a mutex to be thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to encapsulate `B` in a class that has it `mutable`, but when it is const normally only allows `const` access, except that it befriends `A::f`. For example like this (untested code):

```
class A
{
  int f() const;
  int g() const; // some function without exclusive access

  class B_wrapper
  {
    friend int A::f() const;
  public:
    B& get() { return object; }
    B const& get() const { return object; }
  private:
    B& get_mutable() const { return object; }
    mutable B object;
  };
  B_wrapper bw;
};

int A::f() const
{
  B& b = bw.get_mutable(); // allowed due to friend declaration
  tiny_change(b); // since copying "b" is expensive
  int result = compute(b);
  tiny_recover(b); // "b" backs to the original value
  return result;
}

int A::g() const
{
  // B& b = bw.get_mutable();
  //   -> not allowed because B_wrapper::get_mutable() is private
  // B& b = bw.get();
  //   -> not allowed because get() const returns a const reference
  B const& b = bw.get();
  // without casts, only const interface to b is available
}
```